# How to find intersection of two cell arrays which are of type double in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have two 5×5 cells. The cells contain only `double` numeric values.

How do I find an intersection of the elements?

The output should be a cell with common elements, eg., `[x,y]`.

Comment: Take a look at `cellfun` and `ismember`.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out now.

Comment: Since your values are doubles you will likely need to use threshold comparisons to account for rounding inaccuracies.

Comment: If the cells only contain `double` scalar values, consider using stantard numerical arrays (matrices) instead of cells, for efficiency

Comment: I know their exact values so I can round them off.I dont understand which command to use? intersect or ismember command doesnt work.How should I proceed?

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your cells contain numerical matrices of different size, that you want to find the common elements in these matrices (*e.g.* `C1` and `C2`), and get the result as a cell, you can use the following code :

```
e = num2cell(intersect(arrayfun(@(x) C1{x}(:), (1:numel(A))'),...
                       arrayfun(@(x) C2{x}(:), (1:numel(A))')));
```

This code work for matrices of any dimension in the cells.

If you want to find matrices that are equal in both cells, you probably need the isequal function.

If the numerical inside your cells have only one element, you should probably store them as a standard numerical array, as adviced by @luis-mendo